# Magento 2 basic bundle product made from other simple products?

Tags: magento, magento2

Am I missing something or has Magento 2 not got one of the most basic simple functions of a retail site?  I'm fairly new to magento so I might be missing something very obvious here.  I'll try and explain as best I can.

Scenario:

Simple product A is $10 and 
Simple product B is $12

Aim:
Create product C which is $20 (or any price i set manually) and contains 1 x product A and 1 x product B and cannot be edited by the customer and is added to the cart as 1 single item (not 2 separate items) but stock still adjusts correctly on product A and B when it's purchased.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to add product as you are asking for.

-> create bundle product  
-> set dynamic price to no and add price whatever you want to add (http://prntscr.com/mjvqfp) 
-> also set dynamic SKU to no   
-> Add items to bundle products. Set input type = checkbox, make all items default (http://prntscr.com/mjvr4g)

Now you can see your product in frontend, 
-> you will find option for customization (http://prntscr.com/mjvtft)

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: This isn't great because the customer can still edit the products in the bundle, yet the price remains the same. Is there no way to lock the products?